# PHP Return array from recursive function

Tags: php

When I echo out $value['id']. $value['label']; every row is echoed out //that's what I actually want.
But, when I return $result only the first array is returned.. How can I fix this?

Here's the code:

```
    public function recursive_category($tree,$indent=0) {
    $indent++; // Try to get depth of current array
    foreach ($tree as $value) {
        foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
            $indent_str = str_repeat("--", $indent);
            echo $value['id'].' '.$value['label'].'<br>';
            $id[] = $value['id'];
            $label[] = $value['label'];
            if (!empty($value['items'])) {
                self::recursive_category($value['items'],$indent);
            }
        };
    }
    $result = array_combine($id, $label);
    return $result;

}
```

Comment: $id and $label aren't even in scope where you are defining `$result = array_combined($id, $label);` so I am not even sure how you are getting anything returned. Define them outside of your loops.

Comment: added $id = ''; and $label=''; before first foreach loop and still, same thing..

Comment: What does your $tree array looks like?

Comment: Nevermind, I solved this with public $id = [], and public $layout = []. :)